# How can I choose a set of predefined variables from a dictionary using variable keys?

Tags: ansible

Im trying to launch ec2 instances in groups (using group_vars) dynamically in different availability zones with different visibility. I defined a dictionary with relevant az, subnet_id, etc. Visibility is defined in group_vars and I pass in the desired zone in the command with -e arg_zone=a or -e arg_zone=b

```
---
- name: create aws instance
  hosts:
    - web_sb
    - web_qa
    - web_prod

  vars:
    regions:
      uswest2:
        private:
          a:
            subnet_id: "subnet-123"
            availability_zone: "us-west-2a"
            assign_public_ip: no
          b:
            subnet_id: "subnet-456"
            availability_zone: "us-west-2b"
            assign_public_ip: no
        public:
          a:
            subnet_id: "subnet-abc"
            availability_zone: "us-west-2a"
            assign_public_ip: yes
          b:
            subnet_id: "subnet-def"
            availability_zone: "us-west-2b"
            assign_public_ip: yes

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: regions.uswest2.{{ visibility }}.{{ arg_zone }}.subnet_id

    - debug:
        var: regions.uswest2.{{ visibility }}.{{ arg_zone }}.availability_zone

    - debug:
        var: regions.uswest2.{{ visibility }}.{{ arg_zone }}.assign_public_ip


    - name: "ec2 instance created from ami {{ ami_id }}"
      ec2:
        instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
        image: "{{ arg_ami_id }}"
        key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
        instance_tags: {}
        wait: yes
        group: "{{ security_groups }}"
        count: 1

        volumes:
          - device_name: "/dev/sda1"
            volume_type: "gp2"
            volume_size: "{{ os_volume_size }}"
            delete_on_termination: yes

        vpc_subnet_id: regions.uswest2.{{ visibility }}.{{ arg_zone }}.subnet_id
        assign_public_ip: no #regions.uswest2.{{ visibility }}.{{ arg_zone }}.assign_public_ip

        region: "us-west-2"
        zone: regions.uswest2.{{ visibility }}.{{ arg_zone }}.availability_zone
```

The debug statements work as I would expect, but when I try to use those same values in the ec2 task they are not accessing the values. I'm getting errors like

> argument assign_public_ip is of type <type 'str'> and we were unable to convert to bool: The value 'regions.uswest2.private.a.assign_public_ip' is not a valid boolean.  Valid booleans include: 0, 'on', 'f', 'false', 1, 'no', 'n', '1', '0', 't', 'y', 'off', 'yes', 'true'"

and

> The subnet ID 'regions.uswest2.private.a.subnet_id' does not exist

1. what am I doing wrong? (am I going about this completely the wrong way? I realize I could define these in host_vars but I am creating hosts dynamically so im using group_vars to define different classes of hosts) but maybe there is another way I havent considered
2. is there a way to format the variables to access these values from the predefined dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The debug statements work as I would expect, but when I try to use those same values in the ec2 task they are not accessing the values

That's because the `debug: var:` actually secretly converts to `msg: {{ ... }}` wrapped around the `var:` literal, so there are implicit jinja2 mustaches around that expression, causing it to be evaluated

> what am I doing wrong?

You are confusing literal text with a jinja2 expression

> is there a way to format the variables to access these values from the predefined dictionary?

```yaml
        assign_public_ip: '{{ regions.uswest2[visibility][arg_zone].assign_public_ip }}'
```